# Unable to release my gem to github

Tags: git, github, rubygems, bundler

I'm confused as to what is happening here:

```
$ sudo rake install
(in /Users/****/code/parsley)
WARNING:  no rubyforge_project specified
WARNING:  description and summary are identical
  Successfully built RubyGem
  Name: parsley
  Version: 0.1.1
  File: parsley-0.1.1.gem
Executing "ruby -S gem install ./pkg/parsley-0.1.1.gem":
ruby -S gem install ./pkg/parsley-0.1.1.gem
Successfully installed parsley-0.1.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for parsley-0.1.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for parsley-0.1.1...
```

But I notice I no longer have a clean repo, so:

```
 $ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   deleted:    parsley-0.1.1.gem
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

This seems strange to me.  0.1.1 is the current release, so I'm not sure why the gem would be deleted.  I guess in preparation for it to be recreated?  So I commit.  But then when I go to do rake release, I get this error:

```
$ rake release
(in /Users/****/code/parsley)
Pushing master to origin
Generated: parsley.gemspec
parsley.gemspec is valid.
WARNING:  no rubyforge_project specified
WARNING:  description and summary are identical
  Successfully built RubyGem
  Name: parsley
  Version: 0.1.0
  File: parsley-0.1.0.gem
rake aborted!
Permission denied - (./parsley-0.1.0.gem, ./pkg/parsley-0.1.0.gem)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:515:in `rename'
```

I am releasing this to a private repo, that might be important here because I was able to release a test gem to a public repo.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this tutorial on publishing private gems, and everything worked.

http://www.cerebris.com/blog/2011/03/15/creating-and-managing-private-rubygems-with-jeweler-github-and-bundler/